# AutoMapper file size formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I have wrote a ValueResolver to convert a file size to a nicer looking string version.  Problem is, ValueResolver takes a specific object type.

Is there a way to write the same code, but be able to apply it against any number property i want?

here is the ValueResolver

```
public class ImageSizeResolver : ValueResolver<Image, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(Image source)
    {
        if (source.Size == 0)
        {
            return "n/a";
        }

        var exponent = (short)(Math.Min(Math.Floor(Math.Log(source.Size) / Math.Log(1024)), 8));
        var size = source.Size / Math.Pow(1024, exponent);
        var result = size.ToString("0.##");

        switch (exponent)
        {
            case 0:
                return result + "b";
            case 1:
                return result + "kb";
            case 2:
                return result + "mb";
            case 3:
                return result + "gb";
            case 4:
                return result + "tb";
            case 5:
                return result + "pb";
            case 6:
                return result + "eb";
            case 7:
                return result + "zb";
            case 8:
                return result + "yb";
        }

        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

In my autoMapper config file, i apply this like so

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Size, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ImageSizeResolver>())
    .ReverseMap();
```

Now as you can see, i have another class that i want to use this on, but i dont want to have to create a new ValueResolver that does the same thing?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Size, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ImageSizeResolver>())    <--- Will error currently
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: "Will error currently" - What is actually the error (exception?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [wiki for value converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) and the last section there is an example of what you are looking for, but in short you create a converter for the type you are trying to change and then call it a little differently

```
public class SizeResolver : ValueResolver<int, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(int source)
    {
        if (source == 0)
        {
            return "n/a";
        }

        var exponent = (short)(Math.Min(Math.Floor(Math.Log(source) / Math.Log(1024)), 8));
        var size = source/ Math.Pow(1024, exponent);
        var result = size.ToString("0.##");

        switch (exponent)
        {
            case 0:
                return result + "b";
            case 1:
                return result + "kb";
            case 2:
                return result + "mb";
            case 3:
                return result + "gb";
            case 4:
                return result + "tb";
            case 5:
                return result + "pb";
            case 6:
                return result + "eb";
            case 7:
                return result + "zb";
            case 8:
                return result + "yb";
        }

        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Then you call this converter with

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Size, 
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<SizeResolver>()
                         .FromMember(src=> src.Size))
    .ReverseMap();

Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Size, 
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<SizeResolver>()
                         .FromMember(src=> src.Size))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Excellent thank you, it was the FromMember bit that i didnt know about. Thanks again!